# What can i do to learn the Spanish subjunctive mood?

Tags: spanish

I have been learning Spanish for years now, but I have yet to master the subjunctive mood. It is used regularly in speech, but for some reason is not taught until very late in the learning process.

Here is my question: how exactly do I go about learning the subjunctive mood? Should I be doing grammar drills? Is there a book that I could read?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Spanish teacher myself. If you're very disciplined and have a knack for grammar drills, that might work. Honestly, though, the best way to learn it is to pick it up through set phrases you acquire through conversation, reading and listening practice.